Expose docs per default for each API on Azure APIM
I am currently hosting several APIs behind a APIM. I was now planning to expose the docs and wanted to do this programmatically, thus my question:
Is it possible to have a global policy that intercepts traffic to ../<api-service-id>/openapi.json and returns the docs from the requested endpoint without creating a dedicated API route for it?
The below code does not seem to do anything for me:
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <!--Dynamically call the APIM Management API-->
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.EndsWith("/openapi.json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))">
                <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="result" timeout="10" ignore-error="true">
                    <set-url>@("/subscriptions/my-sub/resourceGroups/my-reg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/my-service"  + "/apis/" + context.Request.MatchedParameters.GetValueOrDefault("api-id","") + "?export=true&format=openapi&api-version=2022-09-01-preview")</set-url>
                    <set-method>GET</set-method>
                    <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://management.azure.com/" />
                </send-request>
                <!--Return the response-->
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@((string)(((IResponse)context.Variables["result"]).Body.As<JObject>()["value"]))</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>

EDIT:
With the help of Ikhtesam Afrin´s answer, it generally works. However, it does not solve my specific issue of having to create an endpoint for each of my APIs.
<set-body>@(((IResponse)context.Variables["result"]).Body.As<JObject>().ToString())</set-body>
        </return-response>


Are you getting any error while using this policy?

I am not sure where to look for errors. I get a 404 when trying to curl https://ampi.net/openapi.json

I am using the below policy at global level to get the OpenAPI document and passing the apiId dynamically.
Add the policy as shown below-

<policies>
    <inbound>
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="result" timeout="10" ignore-error="false">
            <set-url>@("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/0e8****5e7c/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/afreeen-apimgmt/apis/" + context.Api.Id + "?export=true&format=openapi&api-version=2022-09-01-preview")</set-url>
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
            <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://management.azure.com/" />
        </send-request>
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@(((IResponse)context.Variables["result"]).Body.As<JObject>().ToString())</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>

Grant API Management Service Reader RBAC role on Resource group level to managed identity by clicking on “Azure role assignments”.
Trace-





Response-


have you created an endpoint in echo-api for it? I do not fully understand how I can utilise this for all services, isn´t a rewrite needed?

.. or a conditional statement?

I didn't create echo api, it will be created automatically when you will create an apim developer plan instance. You need to add it in All Api level to utilise in all the APIs available in a single instance.

No sorry, I meant of you have created a specific endpoint within the echo-api? and what´s the url?

I am using default Url (https://***.azure-api.net/echo/resource?param1=sample) which comes with Echo API and have placed the given policy in All API level.

Thanks, it works! But now every endpoints return the openapi.json. I think, I now need to add the case-logic from before, correct? But I would need an endpoint on each api, say /docs, otherwise it won´t work, also correct?

Yes, It will return .json file content. To add /docs, you can use rewrite policy

The answer does not really solve my issue with having to create routes on all my APIs in order for it to work.

Can you share some screenshots of how you are adding separate routes? In my policy I have achieved it without adding any additional routes. Share your new requirement, I will update my answer accordingly

@Bennimi I see you have added @(((IResponse)context.Variables["result"]).Body.As().ToString()) as edit in question which has solved your issue but it's already these in my policy, have you checked?

yes, and as I said previously, your solution now intercepts every call, regardless whether an endpoint is present in any API defintion or not.

Yes, when you add a policy in global level, it should be dynamic. So that It can work on all the available APIs. Can you share the additional changes you made to get it work?
